# Want to put at least $500/yr away for my niece, but NOT for education. Choices?

Tags: united-states, gifts, utma-ugma

I would like to put money away for my niece.  I'm looking to put it somewhere that she can use the money when she turns 18/21.  Also, I don't want it to be tied to education, in case she would like to use the money to take a trip, buy a car, or education if that's what she so chooses.

I have been reading online but, we all know how that worked out, as I have to figure out who knows what they're talking about. What are my choices in terms of kinds of accounts and how should I weigh them? Any help is greatly appreciated and encouraged.

Comment: Welcome David.  (You seem generous.)  Would you please edit your tags to include what country you (and your niece) live in?  Also, how old is your niece today?  Any relevant information about her parents and their situation would also be helpful to add.

Comment: I am deleting the IRA tag because _you_ cannot set up an IRA for your niece. But, if your niece has _earned_ income (babysitting, paper route, lawn-mowing, snow-shoveling etc) that she could contribute to an IRA, what you _could_ do is give her the money right as a gift and encourage her to put _all_ her earnings into an IRA. (Her parents would likely need to be involved in setting up the IRA if she is a minor).  This way, she still has her earnings to spend right now on whatever she wishes, and you have started her on a good path for the future.

Comment: How old is she now? Does she work at all, even babysitting?

Comment: How much are you considering? In the US you can gift up to about $17k/person/person/year without triggering gift taxes; question would be how to arrange to cover any  taxes due on the account w/out it being a hassle for her. Might be simpler to just set up a beneficial account/trust in her name...?

Comment: @keshlam - $14k/yr for 2014, an unchanged for 2015.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend opening a [UTMA investment account](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Transfers_to_Minors_Act) with any of the major discount brokerage firms (Schwab, Fidelity, etc) and making regular deposits into an index or target fund. Have the statements sent to your niece's address so she can see the growth over time.

The custodian of the account will have control until she turns 18 or 21, then she will have full use of the money.

You have other options (like a 529 account), but those come with restrictions on how the money can be spent.